# Next node in xml with same element name

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I've been working on this problem for a few hours now and I have searched all around with no luck for a solution :(

What I am trying to do is print out names of the nodes, what i have is the amount of nodes that exist so I know how many times to loop but am having the hardest of times retrieving the values

What I have tried:

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(queuecount);
var jobs = QueueXML.SelectSingleNode(xpathjobsfilename).InnerText;
PreviousQueue = jobs.ToString();

//foreach(loop < num)
//{
//    if (CurrentQueue == PreviousQueue)
//    {

//    }
//    else
//    {
//        resultsListView.Items.Clear();
//        resultsListView.Items.Add(jobs[num]);
//    }
//    loop++;
//}

foreach (char JobName in jobs.ToString())
{
    if (CurrentQueue == PreviousQueue)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        resultsListView.Items.Clear();
        resultsListView.Items.Add(jobs[num]);
    }
}
```

Edit: Example XML

```
 <jobs>
    <job>
      <timeleft>0:00:00</timeleft>
      <mb>1419.60536003</mb>
      <msgid></msgid>
      <filename>Extended_Final</filename>
      <mbleft>1274.33209419</mbleft>
      <id>nzo_i7qxxq</id>
    </job>
    <job>
      <timeleft>0:00:00</timeleft>
      <mb>9.22459220886</mb>
      <msgid></msgid>
      <filename>Video2</filename>
      <mbleft>9.22459220886</mbleft>
      <id>2m3dv5</id>
    </job>
  </jobs>
```

I want to retrieve the  job details for each individual jobs

Comment: Could you show and example XML structure and the result you are looking for?

Comment: I just edited the original question with an example

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract?

Comment: why not use **LINQ2XML**.Its a complete replacement to the underlying XmlReader and writer.Its **simple** and its **cool**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ2XML

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXMLfile.xml");

string timeleft,mb,msgid,filename,mbleft,id;

foreach(XElement elm in doc.Descendants().Elements("job"))
{
    timeleft = elm.Element("timeleft").Value; //time left value
    mb = elm.Element("mb").Value; //mb value
    msgid = elm.Element("msgid").Value; //msgid value
    filename = elm.Element("filename").Value; //filename value
    mbleft = elm.Element("mbleft").Value; //mbleft value
    id = elm.Element("id").Value; //id value
}
```

Comment: I get this error:

Error 3 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: @KPS the error caused because you are not assigning the Value to anything..assign all the values to string...

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to loop through your job-nodes.

```
XmlDocument doc = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"/path/to/xml/file");

foreach (XmlNode job in doc.SelectNodes("/jobs/job"))
{
    string filename = job.SelectSingleNode("filename").InnerText;
    double mbleft = double.Parse(job.SelectSingleNode("mbleft").InnerText);
}
```

I am not quite sure what you want to do with it. If you want to use that information throughout your program, I'd create a job datatype and parse the XML document to a `List<Job>`. In any case the above code will enable you to access the information you are after.

Comment: Hmm this is a metro app that I am trying to make and seems like XmlNode namespace is not available

Comment: Error 3 The type or namespace name 'XmlNode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @KPS please buy some good c# book like `c# in a nutshell` and clear all the **basics**..The error is because you have not included `System.Xml` namespace..

Comment: @Anirudha, I agree on the idea that he should get a book. However, XmlNode does not exist in metro style apps and the System.Xml namespace is located somewhere else.

Comment: You guys are correct and I won't argue with that :) 

as for your example, it seems like it never hits the node:

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(xmlResults.ToString());
                foreach (XmlElement job in doc.SelectNodes("/jobs/job"))
                {
                    string filename = job.SelectSingleNode("filename").InnerText;
                    //double mb3 = double.Parse(job.SelectSingleNode("mbleft").InnerText);
                }

Comment: Have you debugged the program and made sure that after `doc.LoadXml` there is actually a XML structure in`doc`?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to add individual job details to a List of dictionary.
It eliminates selecting single node in the loop when there are lot of child nodes. And, more generic.

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(yourXmlString);            
if (doc.HasChildNodes)
{
    System.Xml.XmlNodeList jobLst = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> jobDescription;
    var lstjobDescription = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>();
    string name;
    for (int i = 0; i < jobLst.Count; i++)
    {
        var responseDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        responseDoc.LoadXml(jobLst[i].OuterXml);
        jobDescription = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in responseDoc.SelectNodes("//job/*")) //select all nodes of Job
        {                
            jobDescription.Add(node.Name, node.InnerText);
        }
        lstjobDescription.Add(jobDescription);                       
    }
}
```